# how can I avoid rowSums() dropping rownames?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, statistics

I'm working with a dataframe of more than 100 columns containing counts, like so

```
x<- data.frame (x1 = c(1,0,2,3,4), 
           x2 = c(2,4,5,0,9), 
           x0= c("a","b","c","d","e")) %>% 
  column_to_rownames("x0")


 x1 x2
a  1  2
b  0  4
c  2  5
d  3  0
e  4  9
```

I'd like to add a new column, preferably using
`mutate(counts = rowSums())`
but when I do, the rownames are dropped (i.e. turned to 1,2,3 etc).

My approach would be storing the names in a column using rownames_to_column, and then calculate sums starting from column2, but I can't come up with a suitable code.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dplyr` (or `tidyverse` in general) don't allow rownames.

A way to preserve rownames would be to add rownames as new column perform the data manipulation that you want and move the rownames back.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

x %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  mutate(Total = rowSums(.[-1])) %>% 
  column_to_rownames()

#  x1 x2 Total
#a  1  2     3
#b  0  4     4
#c  2  5     7
#d  3  0     3
#e  4  9    13
```